# Transit visa for the USA?

Tags: visas, usa, peruvian-citizens

How hard is it for Peruvians to get a transit visa for the USA?
I have been told Donald Trump has blocked all south American visas.

Answer (score 2):

There’s no ban but for transiting you need to apply for a C1 (transit) or B1/B2 (business/tourism) non-immigrant visa: https://pe.usembassy.gov/visas/nonimmigrant-visas/

Both B and C visas will require an application, a fee, and an interview. They cost the same so if you’re thinking of visiting the USA in the future or you want to sightsee while you transit, then get the B.

But because of the fee and interview requirements,  it’s oftenjust easier and cheaper to fly directly or to transit via more friendly country such as Mexico or Canada.